# App\Post::categorys must return a relationship instance, but "null" was returned. Was the "return" keyword used? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

> I do not understand why its not working, been on this for days. I am making a website that shows products and each product has a category so i made a relationship with post and category table but it keeps giving this error App\Post::categorys must return a relationship instance, but "null" was returned. Was the "return" keyword used?

```
Post.php: (this is the modal section for Post)

public function categorys(){
$this->hasOne(Category::class);
}

Category.php: (this is the modal section for Category)

public function posts(){
$this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

index.blade.php: (index section to display the name of the categories)

{{  $posts->categorys->name }}


***SOLVED*** added return! But now its giving me another problem 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.post_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from categories where categories.post_id = 1 and categories.post_id is not null limit 1) sorry I am new in Laravel 



 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->integer('price');
        });
    }



  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name');
     });
    }
It keeps giving the error i dont know what seems to be the problem
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to return the relationship. Like

```
public function categorys(){
$this->hasOne(Category::class);
}
```

Should become

```
public function categorys(){
return $this->hasOne(Category::class);
}
```

Comment: oh my bad.. but now its giving me another error .
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.post_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where `categories`.`post_id` = 1 and `categories`.`post_id` is not null limit 1)
sorry I am new in Laravel

Comment: Can you provide your DB structure?

Comment: When you are creating relation, you need to define a foreign key to build the relation. Usually it refers to the id of other table. For example, in categories table it should be post_id. See laravel document https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the foreign key in your migration for the categories. 
You do this like this:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
     });
    }
```

Dont forget to migrate again after droping your Tables.

Comment: it did not work.. gave me an error when i did php artisan migrate:refresh

Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'categories' already exists (SQL: create table `categories` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null, `name` varchar(255) not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Comment: yeah caus you need to drop the table categories cause he is trying to create the table which already existing. Thats the reason why i wrote "Dont forget to migrate again after droping your Tables." ;-)

So-> drop all tables, then php artisan migrate

Comment: well its still giving me an error ;/
i dropped categories table and migrated 
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `shop`.`categories` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `categories` add constraint `categories_post_id_foreign` foreign key (`post_id`) references `posts` (`id`))

Comment: This is too much to work through every error here. Please just check Laravels Documentation https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations